# How to load Atmega328p 8mhz board using board manager

Tags: atmega328

I need to load the Atmega328p 8kHz board definition using the board manager and can not find a way.  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: 8Khz or 8Mhz? AFAIK there is no 8Khz built-in crystal/osscilator.

Comment: Your question doesent make much sense, Are you using a 8MHz crystal or do you want to use the internal 8MHz rc oscillator?

Comment: And.. do you already have the board definition or not?

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming that you have a 3.3V Atmega328P and are using an external 8MHz occilator:**

In the Arduino IDE click on `Tools`.
Scroll down until you see an option starting with the word `Board:`
Select the option called `Arduino Pro or Pro Mini`

Click the `Tools` menu once again.
This time select the option starting with `Processor:`
Select the `Atmega328P (3.3V, 8MHz)`
Done!

Alternatively you can edit the `boards.txt` file located somewhere similar to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr`
Fuse bits can be calculated using one of these online tools:

- http://www.engbedded.com/fusecalc/
- http://eleccelerator.com/fusecalc/

Comment: Assuming that you have a 3.3V Atmega328P and are using an external 8MHz occilator: If this is not the case then please amend your question with the specifics and I will edit my answer to suit.

Comment: The 3.3V part shouldn't matter.

Comment: Was the answer helpful? If so, please accept it by clicking on the "tick" icon next to the answer, and also possibly upvote it. This indicates to other users that you found the answer useful, and it also stops Stack Exchange from periodically "bumping" your question in the hope of getting an accepted answer. Thanks for your understanding and cooperation!